# Parsing with TryParse or Parse when data is theoretically always correct?

Tags: .net, parsing, try-catch

I've looked at a few other questions (especially [Parsing Performance (If, TryParse, Try-Catch)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150114/parsing-performance-if-tryparse-try-catch)), and am thinking about the answers. Is it an abuse of exception handling if the exception shouldn't be thrown? Isn't that the whole point of it? Catching the error in the rare case that something goes wrong?

To be exact, I'm getting some xml data from a service and am wondering if I can assume that it is correct (with the .00000001% that a bit / something else got lost in the internet).

**Edit**
I'll probably use Linq to XML, but the question still stands.

Comment: The "problem" with exception handling is that it always creates some overhead, even when no exception is thrown. I would go with the accepted answer of the question you reference to.

Comment: @Marcel the overhead when it doesn't throw is very minimal, but exceptions aren't a good way to do flow control, for sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I look more at the scenario than the performance; if the **expected behaviour** is that it is valid, I generally use Parse (or ParseExact if available), and let the exception go. Unless I need to raise a *specific* error, in which case TryParse is handy.

If the data *might* be (say) an integer, then TryParse is preferable over Parse+catch.

With LINQ-to-XML: **don't** parse; instead, use the static conversion operators provided; so rather than:

```
...
select int.Parse(node.Value);
```

you should use

```
...
select(int) node;
```

this is even more important for things like DateTime, as it takes into account the standard XML formats. It also does the "expected" thing if the node doesn't exist (i.e. `node` is `null`):

```
select (int?)node;
```

will return a `null` value rather than throwing a `NullReferenceException` (which `node.Value` would do). There are static conversion operators for most expected data-types.

Comment: did you mean cast, instead of "case"?

Comment: `DateTime` is an interesting choice for an example for using the cast. It's one of those places where I'd do the parsing and conversion myself to make sure nothing strange happens.

Comment: @CodeInChaos it depends on what format is expected, I guess; if it is the standard xml date/dateTime/etc then the conversion operator will do the job cleanly

Answer (score 0):

I assume the service usually returns valid data, but I'd still try to guard against failure in an external component. If the service is under your own control and you are *very* sure it will never return invalid data, you can simply use `Parse` and be done. But if it's not under your control, handling failures gracefully is nice.

I'd put a `catch` clause at the outermost level of the code that handles the parsing. And translate any parse error into a generic "invalid data from service" exception with the original exception as inner exception.

Then the calling code can handle that one exception, so it doesn't shut down your whole application.