# How to display the first special character entered in textbox, in a label

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have created a regex function and called it when the data is being saved.

```
public static bool CheckSpecialCharacter(string value)
{
   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"[~`!@#$%^*()=|\{}';.,<>]");
   if (regex.IsMatch(value))
   {
      return false;
   }
   else
   {
      return true;
   }
}
```

Used here:

```
if (ClassName.CheckSpecialCharacter(txt_ExpName1.Text)==false)
{
    lblErrMsg.Text = "Special characters not allowed";
    return;
}
```

Now instead of writing "Special characters not allowed", I want to attach the 1st special character that was entered in the textbox, so
if @ was entered, the message should be read as "Special character @ not allowed"

Is it possible to do this? please help.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code.

```
public static string CheckSpecialCharacter(string value)
{
   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"[~`!@#$%^*()=|\{}';.,<>]");
   var match = regex.Match(value);
   if (match.Success)
   {
      return match.Value;
   }
   else
   {
      return string.empty;
   }
}
```

usage:

```
var value = ClassName.CheckSpecialCharacter(txt_ExpName1.Text);
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value ))
{
    lblErrMsg.Text = value + " Special characters not allowed";
    return;
}
```

OR you can do it by returning bool and adding one `out parameter` in the function, but i will not suggest that.. [check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19190397/side-effects-to-using-out-parameter-in-c-sharp-and-two-returns)

**EDIT - To do the same thing in Javascript**

```
function CheckSpecialCharacter(value)
{
  var res = value.match(/[~`!@#$%^*()=|\{}';.,<>]/g);
  return res == null ? "" : res[0];
}
```

usage:

```
var value = CheckSpecialCharacter(document.getElementById("txt_ExpName1").value);

if(value != "")
{
   document.getElementById("lblErrMsg").innerHTML = value + " Special characters not allowed";
}
```

Comment: There is no need using regex twice. Just use `regex.Match` and then check if the `match.Success` is *true*.

Comment: @KD this worked thank you so much! can you tell me how to do the same thing in javascript?

Comment: i edited the answer, please check if the code works fine with javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static bool CheckSpecialCharacter(string value, out string character)
{
    var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"[~`!@#$%^*()=|\{}';.,<>]");
    var match = regex.Match(value);
    character = regex.Match(value).Value;
    return match.Length == 0;
}
```

and then

```
string character;
if (ClassName.CheckSpecialCharacter(txt_ExpName1.Text, out character) == false)
{
    lblErrMsg.Text = character + " Special characters not allowed";
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `Matches(string)` function from Regex to get the matches then check the first element like this :

```
var regex = new Regex(@"[~`!@#$%^*()=|\{}';.,<>]");
var matches = regex.Matches("This contains # two b@d characters");
if (matches.Count > 0)
{
    var firstBadCharacter = matches[0];
}
```

Then you can wrap the result of your check in an Exception :

```
throw new ArgumentException("Special character '" + firstBadCharacter + "' not allowed.");
```