# How to Parse string into BigInteger?

Tags: c#, string, biginteger

I'm writing my magistracy work in cryptography, and today I was trying to get a BigInteger number from the string. But the only way I find to get BigInteger number from the string was

```
UTF8Encoding Encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
var bytes = Encoding.GetBytes(myString);
var myBigInteger = new BigInteger(bytes);
```

But this is not that way I need. I need something which will return me exactly BigInteger representation of the string. For example, if I have

```
var myString = "1234567890";
```

I want my BigInteger to be

```
BigInteger bi = 1234567890;
```

Comment: I've changed title to match your question (was: "how to get string from `BigInteger`", which looks complete opposite from the post)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use that type's Parse method.

[BigInteger.Parse(string value)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268231.aspx)

It's static. You pass a string and get the corresponding value.

For example:

```
BigInteger reallyBigNumber = BigInteger.Parse("12347534159895123");
```

Comment: Thank you! I forget about this at all =)

Answer (score 1):

I think TryParse is the way you want to go:

```
BigInteger number1;
bool succeeded1 = BigInteger.TryParse("-12347534159895123", out number1);
```

This will not throw an exception if you pass an invalid value.  It will just set the number to 0 if the input string will not convert.  I believe it is faster than Parse as well.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268301.aspx

Comment: It shoudn't be faster, since it uses `Parse` internally. It basically uses a try-catch block, returning `true` in the `try` block and `false `in the `catch`.

Comment: @Abe Why do you think that TryParse is faster than Parse method?

Comment: I read it somewhere a while back.  Here is an excellent SO question where the accepted answer actually shows the difference in performance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150114/parsing-performance-if-tryparse-try-catch

Comment: @Renan, do you have any sources that you could post backing up what you are saying?  Not trying to be a smart ass, just curious to see where you are getting this.

Comment: @AbeMiessler while fidgeting with ILSpy a long time ago I noticed a pattern for all numeric types. I might be wrong, and unfortunately it seems that the latest .NET source codes made available by Microsoft don't include this type. So I can't back up what I said :( please disregard it.

Comment: Interesting question either way.  I'd be curious to see how it's actually implemented.

Answer (score 0):

```
BigInteger bi = BigInteger.Parse("1234567890");
```