# Why does a FormatException within `try` not get caught in `catch`?

Tags: c#, parsing, try-catch, tryparse

I have the following code block and I wonder why a run time error is thrown rather than me being able to handle the exception within `catch` (I put a breakpoint at `int i = 1;` but it is never reached):

```
var stringArray = textRow.Split(Delimiter);

try
{
    var a = DateTime.Parse(stringArray[0]);
    var b = double.Parse(stringArray[2]);
    var c = double.Parse(stringArray[3]);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    int i = 1;

}
```

The following `FormatException` Occurred error is thrown:

```
System.FormatException occurred
  _HResult=-2146233033
  _message=The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.
  HResult=-2146233033
  IsTransient=false
  Message=The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.DateTime.Parse(String s)
  InnerException:
```

I understand that I can use `TryParse` but I like to test whether try/catch will make for better performance because I iterate over this code block many millions of times.

Thanks

Comment: purely out of curiosity, what is a sample contents of textRow so we could simply recreate this code as a small program? :)

Comment: Can you provide the sample data?

Comment: Does it work when you catch `FormatException` explicitly?

Comment: A sample value is: "2014.11.02 22:00:01.996,1.25099,1.25067,1.5,0.37"

Comment: @NikolaiSamteladze, no it does not get caught either.

Comment: im just guessing here, but it DateTime is a struct and mscorlib is unmanaged and since .Net 3 unmanaged exceptions need to be catched explicitly

Comment: The "_HResult" and "_message" looks like an internal exception... can you provide a clip image of your IDE with the exception popup window?

Comment: a side note: dont use try/catch against Tryparse. for the performance difference take a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150114/parsing-performance-if-tryparse-try-catch)

Comment: @J.C, I ticked "Thrown" within Debug/Exceptions/CLR Exceptions. Is that the issue potentially?

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, interesting, I guess that is what I was looking for. I just wondered why the error is still thrown instead of caught.

Comment: If you used this code, breakpoint should be hit. Check you premise...Probably your breakpoints are not activated? Are you running in debug mode? Try to restart VS?...Does any other breakpoint get hit when you run the application?

Comment: @aSharma, tried that already and yes, other breakpoints get hit.

Comment: @MattWolf, I think this is a problem like an internal exception of unmanaged code. Perhaps you should try Fratyx's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try continuing debugging after the exception occurred. The message says that a first chance exception occured but you can continue the program. You should reach the breakpoint then. If there were no try.. catch block you would get an UNHANDLED exception.

Comment: you are accurate, is the first chance exception thrown because I am within the debugging environment? It would not occur in the release but simply caught for me to decide how to handle it and potentially re-throw?

Comment: Yes. You can change this behavior in Visual Studio in menu Debug->Exceptions. There you can decide for which Exceptions you are notified if they are thrown while debugging