# How to extract strings from nodes having same name in xslt

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, xslt, xsd

I have 4 similar nodes with 4 different values. For example, I have the below values.

```
<sample>
        <a>123</a>
        <a>45</a>
        <a>67</a>
        <a>890</a>
</sample>
```

I need to check the length of each node and if its less than 3, then leading zeroes should be appended like below.

```
<sample>
        <a>123</a>
        <a>045</a>
        <a>067</a>
        <a>890</a>
</sample>
```

After appending leading zeroes, I need to concatenate all the values together and pass it as a single string.

```
<a>123045067890</a>
```

Please provide an optimum solution.

Comment: So a good solution wouldn't suffice, it must be optimum?

Comment: This is trivial to do in XSLT: just use the `format-number()` function in a `xsl:for-each` instruction.

Comment: @DanielShillcock Yes I have tried a piece of code.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I have used xsl:for-each command. But when I use that, only the first tag gets taken into account and not the second and other.

Comment: This is the code I have tried. Please put your thoughts.

<xsl:for-each select="//a">
  <ab>
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string-length(//a) &lt; 3">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>ERROR</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </ab>
</xsl:for-each>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="sample">
    <a>
        <xsl:for-each select="a">
            <xsl:value-of select="format-number(., '000')" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </a>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

applied to your example input, returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>123045067890</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

here's one approach using XPath:

```
string xml = @"
    <sample>
        <a>123</a>
        <a>45</a>
        <a>67</a>
        <a>890</a>
    </sample>
";

//load xml
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(xml);

//get all <a> nodes and cast them to List<XmlNode>
var nodes = xdoc.SelectNodes("sample/a")
    .Cast<XmlNode>().ToList();

//iterate through each node and append leading zeroes until length is 3 chars
nodes.ForEach(n => n.InnerText = n.InnerText.PadLeft(3, '0'));
//join all values and add tags to beginning and the end
string concatenatedValues = "<a>" + string.Join("", nodes.Select(x => x.InnerText).ToArray()) + "</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
string xml = @"<sample>
                        <a>123</a>
                        <a>45</a>
                        <a>67</a>
                        <a>890</a>
                    </sample>";

XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
int value = 0;
StringBuilder errorsSb = new StringBuilder();
List<string> a_Nodes = new List<string>();

xmlDoc.Descendants("a").Select(x => x.Value).ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
     if (int.TryParse(x, out value))
          a_Nodes.Add(value.ToString("D3"));
     else
          errorsSb.AppendLine($"Value {value} is not a number");
     });

     string res = String.Join(string.Empty, a_Nodes);
     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(errorsSb.ToString()))
     {
          // handle errors
     }
}
```

Comment: Your code would cause exceptions if non-numeric values are inside the `<a>` tags due to the `int.Parse(x.Value)`

Comment: @bradbury9, so you think it is not good behawior? Better will be just add zeros to any text? Or just skip invalid entry...? I disagree with you. Exception will inform that something is wrong with xml. And catching exception is not a part of the question.

Comment: Exceptions is a so heavy method to control input. Unhandled exceptions? IMHO should not happen. In this case you could use schemas (heavier), a foreach with int32.TryParse (lighter)

Comment: A `foreach` should perform the same as the `Select` and a `TryParse` would perform better than a try-catch + Parse http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150114/parsing-performance-if-tryparse-try-catch

Comment: @bradbury9 daniell's answer isn't necessarily bad; OP did't specify which kind of data is expected in those <a> nodes and daniell assumed it's int, without exceptions. To get better answer, OP should define his/hers question with a bit more details. Anyhow, `TryParse` is better approach.

Comment: @bradbury9, Ok, I've just corrected my answer. Thanks

Comment: @Nino Agree on your comment, personally I deeply disliked the `Int32.Parse`, hence my observation and downvote. Just removed the downvote after the edit.