# try catch statement to turn string into double in vb

Tags: vb.net

I have the following function  which is supposed to check whether the given entry is above 0.0

```
Dim inputstr As String = .Item("conc")

Try
    Dim concentration As Double = CDbl(inputstr)
Catch ex As Exception
    Dim concentration As Double = -1.0
Finally
    Dim concentration As Double = -1.0
End Try

If concentration > 0.0 Then
    err = 1
End If
```

However, I keep getting "concentration is not declared'. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: It is not in scope outside of the try catch. declare it out side then try to set it within the try/catch

Comment: ... and you don't need a try-catch.  Try using `double.TryParse`

Comment: This appears to be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the ultimate goal you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Everything which results in indentation creates a new level of (block) scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Variable Scope**

The variable `Concentration` exists only in the Try block. Therefore, whenever you leave this block, the variable no longer exists.

To solve this, you must declare `Concentration` before the Try.

**Finally Block**

Another problem you will encounter is that `Concentration` will always be -1, because you said so in the `Finally` block, this block is not necessary here.

```
Dim inputstr As String = .Item("conc")
Dim concentration As Double

Try
    concentration = CDbl(inputstr)
Catch ex As Exception
    concentration = -1.0
End Try

If concentration > 0.0 Then
    err = 1
End If
```

A bit of reading about [Variable scope in VB .Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973875.aspx)

And another bit of reading about [Try/Catch blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/try-catch-finally-statement)

**Don't use Try/Catch to do that**

However, as [stated by Fabio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45019745/5897829), you can use [Double.TryParse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx) to do that, it is easier to read and more important, [it is a performance increase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/150123/5897829).

So, in the end, it is better coding practice to do:

```
Dim inputstr As String = .Item("conc")
Dim concentration As Double

If Not Double.TryParse(inputstr, concentration) Then
    concentration = -1.0
End If

If concentration > 0.0 Then
    err = 1
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Changed it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not in scope outside of the try catch. declare it out side then try to set it within the try/catch. Problem though is that it will always end up as `-1.0` because of the `Finally`.

```
Dim inputstr As String = .Item("conc")
Dim concentration As Double = 0.0
Try
    concentration = CDbl(inputstr)
Catch ex As Exception
    concentration = -1.0
End Try

If concentration > 0.0 Then
    err = 1
End If
```

Ultimately you can use [`Double.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

```
Dim inputstr As String = .Item("conc")
Dim concentration As Double = 0.0
If Double.TryParse(inputstr, concentration) AndAlso concentration > 0.0 then
    'Do what you intended
End If
```

Answer (score 2):

While you main problem that 
    `concentration` is not in the scope
    `Finally` will be executed always, doesn't meter was exception thrown or not - so `concentration` will be always set to `-1.0`
    - you still don't need to use `Try .. Catch` approach. `Double.TryParse` will handle it in one line.

```
Dim concentration As Double = 0.0
Double.TryParse(.Item("conc"), concentration)

err = If(concentration > 0.0, 1, 0)
```

`Double.TryParse(inputstr, concentration)` - will set `concentration` to converted double value or to default value, which is `0.0` for `double` type if string is not in correct format.

Answer (score 1):

How about using VB.Net, and use `Double.TryParse` or `Double.Parse`

Which would make your code something like

```
dim concentration as Double = -1
'dont really know where this one is coming from though
err = 0

if Double.TryParse(inputstr, concentration) then
    if concentration > 0.0 then
        err = 1
    end if
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

in fact, you have 2 issues with your code

one `concentration` need to be declared before the try
second remove the finally otherwise it will **ALWAYS** be -1.0