# How to resolve "The name *** does not exist in the current context" error?

Tags: c#, try-catch

I'm trying to add a Try/Catch block to this code but I can't figure out what to change to make it work..

Any suggestions?
Getting this error:

> "Error CS0103  The name 'fahrenheit' does not exist in the current context"

```csh
class Program
{
    static int FahrenheitToCelsius(int fahrenheit)
    {
        int celsius = ((fahrenheit - 32) * 5) / 9;
        return celsius;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int celsius;

        Console.WriteLine("Hello! Welcome to the sauna!");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your desired degrees in Fahrenheit: ");

        do
        {
            try
            {
                int fahrenheit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
            }

            celsius = FahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit);
            Console.WriteLine("The sauna is now set to " + fahrenheit + 
                " degrees Fahrenheit, which equals to " + celsius + " degrees Celsius.");

            if (celsius < 25)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Way too cold! Turn the heat up: ");
            }
            else if (celsius < 50)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Too cold, turn the heat up: ");
            }
            else if (celsius < 73)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Just a little bit too cold, turn the heat up a " + 
                    "little to reach the optimal temperature: ");
            }
            else if (celsius == 75)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The optimal temperature has been reached!");
            }
            else if (celsius > 77)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Too hot! Turn the heat down: ");
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("The sauna is ready!");
            {
            }
        } while (celsius < 73 || 77 < celsius);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just define `farenheit` outside the scope of the `try` block if you want to access it outside that block. Perhaps where you define `celcius`?

Comment: That being said, you should really use `int.TryParse` rather than exception handling to validate the user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
try
{
    int fahrenheit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

`fahrenheit` will exist only inside `try {}` block while you try to use it later. Move it to parent scope:

```
int fahrenheit;
while (true)
{
   try
   {
        fahrenheit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        break;
   }
   catch (FormatException)
   {
      continue;
   }
}
celsius = FahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit);
```

Note that in case of `FormatException` there is nothing to calculate, so I added `while (true)` loop with `continue` inside `catch` block. Also I recommend to use `Int32.TryParse` method here, it will return parsing result as `bool` instead of raising exception.

Comment: Oh, I see! Changed the code like you said, now I'm getting this error instead:
Error CS0165 Use of unassigned local variable 'celsius'

Comment: yeah, in this case on first run `celsius` wasn't set but it used in `while (celsius < 73 || 77 < celsius);` See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks! Solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems here. The main one is that `Fahrenheit` needs to be declared outside the `try` block since you're using it outside that block (variables are scoped to the block in which they're declared). Moving it to where you define `celsius` seems logical, although it's usually best to declare variables at the innermost scope required.

The second thing is that you should use the [`int.TryParse`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjJtKDfk_3gAhWpIjQIHSFBCXgQFjAAegQIChAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdotnet%2Fapi%2Fsystem.int32.tryparse&usg=AOvVaw35Ul21c7qYu7DttNERjnwp) method to validate the user input rather than a `try/catch` block. It performs much better and is cleaner, more intentional code. Read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150114/parsing-performance-if-tryparse-try-catch) for more information.

This method returns `true` if successful, and takes in a `string` to parse (we use the return value of `Console.ReadLine()` directly below), and an `out` parameter that will be set to the converted integer if successful.

These changes might look something like:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int celsius;

    Console.WriteLine("Hello! Welcome to the sauna!\n");

    do
    {
        // Use a loop with TryParse to validate user input; as long as
        // int.TryParse returns false, we continue to ask for valid input
        int fahrenheit;
        do
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter your desired degrees in Fahrenheit: ");

        } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out fahrenheit));

        celsius = FahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit);

        // Rest of loop code omitted...

    } while (celsius < 73 || 77 < celsius);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing that out, had to use try/catch on this course, but will definetely use int.TryParse in the future!

Answer (score 0):

You could do a few different things.

1. You could put at the top of the code near `int celcisus` also `int fahrenheit`
2. You could put all the code in the `try` and if anything failed it'd go to the catch.

Answer (score 0):

Your have to declare the variable in the outer scope handle the exception in order to have a calid C# program.

This way, you'll end up on your variable assigned when the conversion is successful, otherwise you simply reask the user the value:

```
class Program
{
    static int FahrenheitToCelsius(int fahrenheit)
    {
        int celsius = ((fahrenheit - 32) * 5) / 9;
        return celsius;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int celsius;

        Console.WriteLine("Hello! Welcome to the sauna!");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your desired degrees in Fahrenheit: ");
        do
        {
            // you have to declare the variable out of the scope
            int fahrenheit;
            try
            {
                fahrenheit = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                // and here you have to handle the exception
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid value.");
                continue;                    
            }

            celsius = FahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit);
            Console.WriteLine("The sauna is now set to " + fahrenheit + " degrees Fahrenheit, which equals to " + celsius + " degrees Celsius.");

            if (celsius < 25)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Way too cold! Turn the heat up: ");
            }
            else if (celsius < 50)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Too cold, turn the heat up: ");
            }
            else if (celsius < 73)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Just a little bit too cold, turn the heat up a little to reach the optimal temperature: ");
            }
            else if (celsius == 75)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The optimal temperature has been reached!");
            }
            else if (celsius > 77)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Too hot! Turn the heat down: ");
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("The sauna is ready!");
            {
            }
        } while (celsius < 73 || 77 < celsius);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```